# How to pass vector<T> between library/module boundary using hourglass pattern?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, hourglass

The question is related to a talk by Stefanus Du Toit on hourglass pattern. Its a great talk, really helpful for library writers.

Youtube Link: https://youtu.be/PVYdHDm0q6Y

Slideshare Link: http://www.slideshare.net/StefanusDuToit/cpp-con-2014-hourglass-interfaces-for-c-apis

**Ok here is the question:**

Say I have to pass a `std::vector<MyObject>` across the library boundary. What is the best way to do this using hourglass pattern. I am concerned about the performance as well as keeping a clean interface. Given below is a set of example interfaces that I want to implement.

Clientside C++ interface:

```
void MyLibraryClass::DoSomething(const std::vector<MyObject>& objs);
```

C Interface:

```
???? (Not sure what is the best practice here)
```

Internall library C++ interface:

```
MyInternalLibraryClass::DoSomething(const std::vector<MyObjectImpl>& objs);
```

Hope this explains my question.

Answer (score 0):

Best would to pass an array internally:

```
void do_something(MyObject* array, size_t count);
```

The internal class use something like `std::span` in its interface, since you are not modifying the vector, it would be more flexible and shouldn't require that much code changes.